# How to convert number to string in Linq to Entities without pulling into local object

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have a query that fetches hierarchical data from the db into an object of structure:

```
class HierarchicalData {
  public int ID {get; set;}
  public string Description {get; set;}
  public IEnumerable<HierarchicalData> Children {get; set;}
}
```

I'm comfortable with how to query the data.  The problem comes when one of my hierarchical elements needs to use a number for `Description`.  I can't use `.ToString()` because Linq to Entities doesn't have a SQL translation for that.  And I don't want to pull all the data into memory just so that I can call `.ToString()` - that would be hugely inefficient.

I just want some kind of expression that can convert a number to a string on the database side.

Comment: Why do you have a problem with descriptions that look like numbers?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I don't understand your comment - I don't have a problem with descriptions that look like numbers.  In fact, that's exactly what I want...

Comment: So what's not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SqlFunctions.StringConvert(double)` in Linq to Entities

- MSDN Example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456858.aspx
- SqlFunctions Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx

Comment: Oh!  I never asked a question before so I didn't know that was the case.  I will be deleting these comments in an hour as they are useless for the future.